# Handling async code to combine multiple returned responses

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, promise

I am working on some async code that queries the github API.  each API call I'm making runs through this code and I hit the 'weeksOfYear' console log.  What I am trying to do is bundle all of these api calls into one big array so I can work on all the data together.  I believe this would involve a callback, but I'm not sure where to put it.  I've included my code below.

I believe it is returning this way because it is all inside of one promise.  When I try to add another promise to the code, I get an error that says 'then is undefined.'  This is because I need to return a promise object.  So, I think the solution would be to use a callback.

Thanks!

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://api.github.com/orgs/lodash/repos' ,
  contentType: 'application/json',
  beforeSend: function(xhr){
      return xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "token adbfde986475bbee66b2e22b4375be4d34adc098")
    }
})
.then(function (data){
  // console.log('GOT THIS DATA', data);
  return data.map(function(val){
      return val.name;
    });
})
.then(function (newData){
  newData.forEach(function(repoName){
    pagination(repoName, function(storage) {
      storage = storage.filter(function(PR){
        if(PR.merged_at !== null){
          return true;
           }
        })
        var weeksOfYear = {};
        console.log('STORAGE HERE IS', storage);
        storage.filter(function(mergedPR){
          if (moment(mergedPR.merged_at).year() === 2016){
            return true;
          }
        }).forEach(function(mergedPR){
          var weekMerged = moment(mergedPR.merged_at).week();
            if(!weeksOfYear[weekMerged]){
              weeksOfYear[weekMerged] = 1;
              // weeksOfYear[yearMerged] = yearMerged
            }else{
              weeksOfYear[weekMerged] += 1;
              // weeksOfYear[moment(mergedPR.merged_at).year()] = moment(mergedPR.merged_at).year()
            }
          })
          console.log('weeks of Year are', weeksOfYear)
        })
      })
    })
```

This is what pagination looks like:

```
var pagination = function (repoName, callback) {
      var num = 1;
      var storage = [];
      function recursiveHelper(repoName, num){
         $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/lodash/' + repoName + '/pulls?state=closed&page=' + num,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        beforeSend: function(xhr){
          return xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "token adbfde986475bbee66b2e22b4375be4d34adc098")
        }
      })
      .then(function(numPullRequests){
        // console.log('numPullRequests', numPullRequests);
        storage = storage.concat(numPullRequests);
        if(numPullRequests.length !== 30){
          return callback(storage);
        }

        recursiveHelper(repoName, num + 1);
      })
        // console.log('this value is', numPullRequests);
      }

      recursiveHelper(repoName, num)

}
```

Comment: is `pagination(repoName, function(storage) {` an asynchronous function? and when you say `bundle all of these api calls` - which "api calls" are you referring to, as the only function that looks remotely like an api call is `pagination`

Comment: Yes it is, it is too big to paste into comments, unfortunately.  It continually makes calls to the github API to collect different different pull requests (the most you can retrieve at a time is 30, and then concats them into an array.

I've added the rest of my code, I hope that clarifies things.

Comment: This sounds like a job for `Promise.all`.  You can build up an array of promises and pass them to `Promise.all`.  The function passed to the `then` block of `Promise.all` will receive an array of the results on the individual promises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, since pagination is asynchronous, and doesn't return a promise (even though it uses promises! but it's recursive nature makes it what it is) minimal change to your existing code yields this

```
...
.then(function(newData) {
    // use Array#map and Promise.all ...
    return Promise.all(newData.map(function(repoName) {
        // create a Promise
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            pagination(repoName, function(storage) {
                storage = storage.filter(function(PR) {
                    if (PR.merged_at !== null) {
                        return true;
                    }
                })
                var weeksOfYear = {};
                console.log('STORAGE HERE IS', storage);
                storage.filter(function(mergedPR) {
                    if (moment(mergedPR.merged_at).year() === 2016) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }).forEach(function(mergedPR) {
                    var weekMerged = moment(mergedPR.merged_at).week();
                    if (!weeksOfYear[weekMerged]) {
                        weeksOfYear[weekMerged] = 1;
                        // weeksOfYear[yearMerged] = yearMerged
                    } else {
                        weeksOfYear[weekMerged] += 1;
                        // weeksOfYear[moment(mergedPR.merged_at).year()] = moment(mergedPR.merged_at).year()
                    }
                });
                console.log('weeks of Year are', weeksOfYear);
                // resolve the promise in the callback
                resolve(weeksOfYear);
            });
        });
    }));
}).then(function(result) {
    // results is an array of weeksOfYear
});
```

> However, if you change `pagination` to return a promise, like this

```
var pagination = function(repoName) {
    var num = 1;
    var storage = [];
    function recursiveHelper(repoName, num) {
        return $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/lodash/' + repoName + '/pulls?state=closed&page=' + num,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                return xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "token adbfde986475bbee66b2e22b4375be4d34adc098")
            }
        })
        .then(function(numPullRequests) {
            // console.log('numPullRequests', numPullRequests);
            storage = storage.concat(numPullRequests);
            if (numPullRequests.length !== 30) {
                return storage;
            }
            return recursiveHelper(repoName, num + 1);
        });
        // console.log('this value is', numPullRequests);
    }
    return recursiveHelper(repoName, num);
};
```

your code can be changed to this

```
...
.then(function(newData) {
    // again, use Array#map and Promise.all
    return Promise.all(newData.map(function(repoName) {
        // no need for new Promise as pagination returns a promise
        return pagination(repoName)
        .then(function(storage) {
            storage = storage.filter(function(PR) {
                if (PR.merged_at !== null) {
                    return true;
                }
            })
            var weeksOfYear = {};
            console.log('STORAGE HERE IS', storage);
            storage.filter(function(mergedPR) {
                if (moment(mergedPR.merged_at).year() === 2016) {
                    return true;
                }
            }).forEach(function(mergedPR) {
                var weekMerged = moment(mergedPR.merged_at).week();
                if (!weeksOfYear[weekMerged]) {
                    weeksOfYear[weekMerged] = 1;
                    // weeksOfYear[yearMerged] = yearMerged
                } else {
                    weeksOfYear[weekMerged] += 1;
                    // weeksOfYear[moment(mergedPR.merged_at).year()] = moment(mergedPR.merged_at).year()
                }
            });
            console.log('weeks of Year are', weeksOfYear);
            // just return weeksOfYear
            return weeksOfYear;
        });
    }));
}).then(function(result) {
    // results is an array of weeksOfYear
});
```

> note: if you don't have Promise available

replace

```
return Promise.all(newData.map(function(repoName) {
```

with

```
return $.when.apply($, newData.map(function(repoName) {
```

and

```
}).then(function(result) {
    // results is an array of weeksOfYear
});
```

with

```
}).then(function() {
    // arguments will be weeksOfYear
});
```

For the first answer, you'll also need to change

```
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    pagination(repoName, function(storage) {
        //... snip
        console.log('weeks of Year are', weeksOfYear);
        // resolve the promise in the callback
        resolve(weeksOfYear);
    });
 });
```

to

```
var d = $.Deffered();
pagination(repoName, function(storage) {
     //... snip
     console.log('weeks of Year are', weeksOfYear);
     // resolve the promise in the callback
     d.resolve(weeksOfYear);
});
return d.promise();
```

Comment: Sorry, if you tested the second code and it borked, I had a return in the wrong place

Comment: `Promise.all()` will certainly work if available but there's no evidence that it is. All we know about is `jQuery` ..... therefore `jQuery.when()`.

Comment: Noted: added changes for using `$.when`

Comment: Thanks so much!  This was a great answer : )